# Truly unexpected error handling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, error-handling, navigation

You test your Flutter app thoroughly, but still want to ensure users get a friendly message displayed on a production-looking widget in case errors you haven't account for occur. These errors may be thrown because either you missed some catch-all blocks or you deliberately caught certain errors only and considered everything else to be truly exceptional. These truly exceptional cases are the ones you want to deal with and they may occur in any phase (build, rendering, etc.) and come from any source (flutter, platform).

So you program

1. ErrorWidget.builder
2. FlutterError.onError
3. PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError

in such a way that users are presented with a custom error widget featuring a generic error message and a way to navigate back to the main app screen, the one that the app displays once started. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the main app screen never crashes.

The generic error widget should be defined in a class of its own (extending StatefulWidget, StatelessWidget or any other appropriate widget class). The navigation should be achieved via the app bar back button or, if too complicated, via a button displayed below the generic error message.

How would you program 1., 2. and 3. to achieve the above?

I'd like to find a generic way to deal with these unaccounted for error cases and use it across Flutter projects.